# After removing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from single boot, Win7 working for at most 5min

Tags: windows-7

Well, I installed Ubuntu a few days ago. But then I made a Start up Disk so that I can use Ubuntu with my thumb drive.

Then I installed back Windows 7 Ultimate. While Installation, I was unable to remove a **DRIVE** which was taking 10GB space, I don't even know about that drive that when It was made. It showed **SYSTEM** type on It.

I ignored and continued my installation.

Now, I'm unable to work on Win 7 for more than 5-8 min.
It just stops instantly, the screen goes OFF (not Blank).
And trys to reboot.
But Nothing happens, the screen remains OFF and No BIOS or Boot loads up.

It simply starts the Processor and Its FAN and stops, and try to boot again.

But nothing Happens.